# ZMQ Pub-Sub latency spikes

Tags: python, c++, zeromq, pyzmq, low-latency

I'm using a ZMQ pub-sub to pass messages from a C++ program to a Python script.

I'm passing around 5000 messages per second, and they vary in weight from 100 to 4500 bytes, with an average of about 300 bytes each. On average, I'm sending about 2.5 megabytes worth of data per second via this socket.

My monitoring script works like this:

- Bind C++ program to the socket and leave it running.
- Add a timestamp to each message going out of the C++ program.
- Start python script, connect to socket, receive msg, get a timestamp and subtract the output timestamp, get the latency measurement.
- Keep track of the average latency rolling over x messages.

My problem:
When I start the script, the socket latency hovers around 200 microseconds. That's within my expectations, and seems correct. However, after 1 minute avg latency is around 1.5 milliseconds, around 10-15ms after 4 minutes, and stabilizes at around 50ms after 10 minutes.
If I restart my Python script, latency goes back to 200 microseconds. I don't think the problem is message backlogging because if that was the case, the latency would keep increasing, and it would occasionally decrease too, instead of increasing linearly up to a certain threshold in a predictable way.

What could possibly be the issue?
Is there a way to either change ZMQ settings to try and improve this, or see if it's having some internal backlogging problem?

Comment: We really can't say much about this without doing some extensive profiling, but that is something you can do. Do you have a way of monitoring message pressure within the app? Do you have telemetry on messages per second? Does your process use up more and more memory, or have background tasks that could interfere? Look at your resource utilization very carefully.

Comment: One idea: Try ripping out anything and everything that actually does stuff and just pong messages back and forth to see if that removes the problem. If it does, start adding things back in until you can reproduce the problem. Alternatively, flood the system with messages to see how it behaves under severe load. Sometimes you have a thread/memory/resource leak that doesn't quite cause a fault under lighter load, but if you can get it to blow a gasket that'll hint at where you should look.

Answer (score 0):

When you mentioned 50ms I immediately related to [the Nagle algorithm](https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2020/10/14/lag/).

However as you are saying that you use ZMQ on both sides and [Nagle is disabled by default](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/tcp.cpp#L64) then I am sort of taken back.

Here are some ideas to debug:

1. Start the C++ process under strace with `strace <binary> args` and look at the logs, in particular the ones right after the socket creation. Check that `TCP_NODELAY` is set on the socket.
2. Start wireshark as admin and capture on the interface you are publishing. [Follow the given TCP stream](https://documentation.help/Wireshark/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html) and try to check for blatant errors (eg retransmission) and patterns.