# Strange increase in latency of ZeroMQ between c# and python

Tags: python, c#, tcp, zeromq, low-latency

I'm trying to send images from C# running on win 11 to a python server running on WSL2.

I'm using ZeroMQ to send byte arrays, but as soon as the byte arrays cross a threshold (~8kb) the latency spikes from 0.3ms to 50ms. This 50ms latency remains until I get to ~74KB. Then it reduces back to about 0.3ms.

I have seen references to Nagle's algorithm (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75190133/1988046) but it seems that Nagle's is disabled by default in zeromq (http://wiki.zeromq.org/area:faq).

[Update] I ran it with a local install of python on the Win 11 side and did not see this problem at all, even though I was using exactly the same code file.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

**C# Client**

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;

namespace ChatGptUdp;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var socket = new RequestSocket();
        socket.Connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
        var data = new byte[100000];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) data[i] = (byte) i;

        for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var targetLength = 1000 * i;
            var chunk = data.Take(targetLength).ToArray();
            var elapsed = new List<TimeSpan>();
            for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                socket.SendFrame(chunk);
                var response = socket.ReceiveFrameString();
                sw.Stop();
                elapsed.Add(sw.Elapsed);
            }
            // I skip the first 50 so that I ignore any startup delays. 
            // I don't think that will happen with this version of my algorithm, but just to be sure.
            Console.Out.WriteLine($"{targetLength}: {elapsed.Skip(50).Average(s => s.TotalMilliseconds)}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Python Server**

```py
import zmq
import numpy as np
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
print("Server connected")
while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    data = {
        'str': 'Hello there!'
    }
    socket.send_json(data)
```

**Latency results**

| Size in bytes | Time in ms |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 0.3235700000000001 |
| 2000 | 0.28261 |
| 3000 | 0.28320400000000007 |
| 4000 | 0.280366 |
| 5000 | 0.35102799999999995 |
| 6000 | 0.2954839999999999 |
| 7000 | 0.30082 |
| 8000 | 0.27812799999999993 |
| 9000 | 50.00155000000001 |
| 10000 | 49.99915800000001 |
| 11000 | 50.00125 |
| 12000 | 50.008024 |
| ... | ... |
| 70000 | 50.004577999999995 |
| 71000 | 49.986256 |
| 72000 | 49.99861 |
| 73000 | 49.998368 |
| 74000 | 2.3343279999999997 |
| 75000 | 0.337194 |
| 76000 | 1.37548 |
| 77000 | 0.34829199999999993 |
| 78000 | 0.31957599999999997 |
| 79000 | 0.3393840000000001 |
| 80000 | 0.34001999999999993 |

Comment: Is that a one time measurement or is that consistently repeatable?

Comment: It's repeatable. And it's always at 8kb and 74kb

Comment: And sorry about the data at the end. It's a well formatted table in the preview. Not sure why it breaks in practice.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you go from big to small? Or start somewhere in the middle? Or even randomly chosen sizes?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. Running in random order produced an identical distribution.